# What could cause a 500 error in a Nuxt.js app after updating dependencies, without any error messages in the console?

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js

I recently updated some dependencies in my Nuxt app, and now I'm unable to start the app. When I try to access the app at localhost:3000, I receive a 500 error. However, when I check the server console in my terminal, I don't see any errors being thrown.

The error message I'm seeing in the browser console is:

```
500
[vite-node] [plugin:vite:import-analysis] [VITE_ERROR] /@fs./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.mjs

import { createSSRApp, createApp, nextTick } from "vue";
import { $fetch } from "ofetch";
import { baseURL } from "#build/paths.mjs";
import { createNuxtApp, applyPlugins, normalizePlugins } from "#app";
import "#build/css";
import _plugins from "#build/plugins";
import RootComponent from "#build/root-component.mjs";
import { appRootId } from "#build/nuxt.config.mjs";
if (!globalThis.$fetch) {
  globalThis.$fetch = $fetch.create({
    baseURL: baseURL()
  });
}
let entry;
const plugins = normalizePlugins(_plugins);
if (true) {
  entry = async function createNuxtAppServer(ssrContext) {
    const vueApp = createApp(RootComponent);
    const nuxt = createNuxtApp({ vueApp, ssrContext });
    try {
      await applyPlugins(nuxt, plugins);
      await nuxt.hooks.callHook("app:created", vueApp);
    } catch (err) {
      await nuxt.callHook("app:error", err);
      nuxt.payload.error = nuxt.payload.error || err;
    }
    return vueApp;
  };
}
if (false) {
  if (true && import.meta.webpackHot) {
    import.meta.webpackHot.accept();
  }
  entry = async function initApp() {
    const isSSR = Boolean(window.__NUXT__?.serverRendered);
    const vueApp = isSSR ? createSSRApp(RootComponent) : createApp(RootComponent);
    const nuxt = createNuxtApp({ vueApp });
    try {
      await applyPlugins(nuxt, plugins);
    } catch (err) {
      await nuxt.callHook("app:error", err);
      nuxt.payload.error = nuxt.payload.error || err;
    }
    try {
      await nuxt.hooks.callHook("app:created", vueApp);
      await nuxt.hooks.callHook("app:beforeMount", vueApp);
      vueApp.mount("#" + appRootId);
      await nuxt.hooks.callHook("app:mounted", vueApp);
      await nextTick();
    } catch (err) {
      await nuxt.callHook("app:error", err);
      nuxt.payload.error = nuxt.payload.error || err;
    }
  };
  entry().catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error while mounting app:", error);
  });
}
export default (ctx) => entry(ctx);

at /@fs./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.mjs
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-beta.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/supabase": "^0.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formkit/addons": "^0.16.5",
    "@formkit/nuxt": "^0.16.5",
    "@formkit/tailwindcss": "^0.16.5",
    "@formkit/themes": "^0.16.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.2",
    "@hcaptcha/vue-hcaptcha": "^0.3.2",
    "@nuxtjs/algolia": "^1.5.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.1.3",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@vueuse/motion": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^7.5.0",
    "is-eu-member": "^1.0.6",
    "maska": "^2.1.7",
    "tailwind-css-variables": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwindcss-hyphens": "^0.1.0",
    "trie-search": "^1.3.6",
    "vue-number-animation": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-tailwind-datepicker": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-uuid": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

This is my `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
import postcss from './config/postcss'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' },
    },
    pwa: {
        manifest: {
            name: 'RightsPlus',
            description: "Fluggastrechte",
            theme_color: '#f97316',
            short_name: 'RightsPlus'
        }
    },
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/algolia',
        '@nuxtjs/i18n',
        '@formkit/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/supabase',
    ],
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    ],
    nitro: {
        compressPublicAssets: true,
    },
    formkit: {
        configFile: '~/formkit.config.ts',
    },
    css: [
        '~/assets/css/main.scss',
        '~/assets/css/transitions.css',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
    ],
    i18n: {
        vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts' // if you are using custom path, default 
    },
    postcss,
    sourcemap: {
        server: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        client: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            google: {
                key: process.env.GOOGLE_KEY,
                placeId: process.env.GOOGLE_PLACE_ID
            },
            flight: {
                aviationstack: process.env.AVIATIONSTACK_KEY,
                flighlabs: process.env.FLIGHTLABS_KEY,
                key: process.env.APP_KEY,
                appId: process.env.APP_ID
            }
        },
    }
})
```

Anyone got a hunch as to where to start looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a .nuxt build or cache related issue. Try to remove the `.nuxt` and `node_modules/.cache` directories and restart nuxt. Does this help? Also note that you are using nuxt version 3.0.0 while the current official release of nuxt is at version **3.4.3**. All the prior release changelogs do not seem to indicate there to be any breaking changes, only bugfixes and performance improvements. So another option would be to just simply update nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

this might sounds weird but in some cases(especially in docker environment), based on [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20446) on official nuxt repo on github, your app name should not be the "app"
just change WORKDIR (or app name)  from **/app** to any random folder, ex. /frontend
or if you want to init a project using npx, just don't select the name "app" as your project name

```
npx nuxi@latest init app                ### don't use this one
npx nuxi@latest init <project-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem. Updated my web template, which used Nuxt 3.0.0, to latest 3.9.0 and had the same symptoms. Nuxt compiled fine within console, but had a 500 error on visit. Something about `head.addheadobjs is not a function nuxt`.

Fix:

Go in `package.json`. Manually find the latest versions of vue, vuetify and nuxt. Manually write those versions into `package.json`. You may need to update other packages as well, but my website was fixed after updating those 3.

(At your own risk) Delete the following folders/files: `.nuxt`, `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`. These will all be autoregenerated. I am not a Nuxt/Vue expert, I don't know if you ever need to manually edit files in those folders, so please properly back up in case of need.

Run `npm install` or whatever your pkg flavor is

Start the website.

If this does not work for you, look at the call stack and try to guess which package is causing the error, and update it manually.